# Edit and View Page of Task only specific fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-design-system, tasks

How do you edit and display view a task with specific fields I can't use force since it will display all the fields

Comment: what do you mean by I can't use force since it will display all the fields?

Comment: <force:recordView recordId="a02D0000006V8Ov" /> this one. I cannot also use lightning:recordViewForm  since it did not support Task object